# Insert multiple input value in database

Tags: php, sql, database, arrays, loops

Tried to insert multiple input value in database but inserting only one table.. Please check and help. Thanks

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" id="database" name="database" >
<?php
foreach($_POST['url_link'] as $value)
{
    echo '<input type="text" name="url_db[]" size="150" value="'.$value.'"/><br />';
}
?>
<br><hr>Categories:<select name="cat" id="cat">
<option value="Mobile">Mobile
<option value="T-Shirt">T-Shirt
</select>

Website:<input type="text" size="50" value="" name="web" id="web"/><input type="submit" value="Save to DB>>" name="datasub"/>
</form>
```

Insert.php -

```
  // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $count = count($_POST['url_db']);
    if (isset($_POST['url_db'])) {
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

            $urllink = $_POST['url_db'][$i];
            $web = $_POST['web'];
            $cat = $_POST['cat'];

            $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (web, urllink, cat) VALUES ('$web', '$urllink', '$cat')";
            if(!($result = mysql_query($sql))){
                "<BR>Error Adding!!<BR>".mysql_error();
                   exit();
            }
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    }
    ?>
```

For information - I am trying insert a multiple url link using input box with categories name (dropdown list) and website name.
url_db[]-

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" id="database" name="database">
<input type="text" name="url_db[]" size="150" value="http://www.google.dk/imghp?hl=da&amp;tab=wi"><br>
<input type="text" name="url_db[]" size="150" value="http://maps.google.dk/maps?hl=da&amp;tab=wl"><br>
<input type="text" name="url_db[]" size="150" value="https://play.google.com/?hl=da&amp;tab=w8"><br>
<input type="text" name="url_db[]" size="150" value="http://www.youtube.com/?gl=DK&amp;tab=w1"><br>
<input type="text" name="url_db[]" size="150" value="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm"><br><br>

<hr>Categories:<select name="cat" id="cat">
<option value="Mobile">Mobile
</option><option value="T-Shirt">T-Shirt
</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You redirect IN your for-loop.

It should be like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['url_db'])) {
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

        $urllink = $_POST['url_db'][$i];
        $web = $_POST['web'];
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];

        $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (web, urllink, cat) VALUES ('$web', '$urllink', '$cat')";
        if(!($result = mysql_query($sql))){
            "<BR>Error Adding!!<BR>".mysql_error();
               exit();
        }
    }
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

EDIT: 
**You should really escape your values before inserting them into the query.**

I suggest this:

```
if (isset($_POST['url_db'])) {
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            //escape with mysqli_real_escape_string or PDO::quote() (mysql_real_escape_string) is deprecated
            $urllink = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['url_db'][$i]);
            $web = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['web']);
            $cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['cat']);

            $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (web, urllink, cat) VALUES ('$web', '$urllink', '$cat')";
            if(!($result = mysql_query($sql))){
                "<BR>Error Adding!!<BR>".mysql_error();
                   exit();
            }
        }
        header("location:index.php");
    }
```

For further info see:

[mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

[PDO::quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

[mysql_real_escape_string() [DEPRECATED]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Same problem only inserting an one table - every time i tried to insert the URL links i need to change the "web" name also otherwise its shows blank page without error. why?

Comment: Please show us the contents of `$_POST['url_db']` in your question.

Comment: Updated please check - post

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting within forloop. for best practice Create inputs like this

```
<?php
  foreach($_POST['url_link'] as $key=>$value)
  {
      echo '<input type="text" name="url_db[]" size="150" value="'.$value.'"/><br />';
  }
  ?>
```

Then your insert code will be like this.

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


if (isset($_POST['url_db'])) {

    print_r($_POST['url_db']) ;   // Make sure you have more than one indexes in array

 foreach($_POST['url_db'] as $key=>$urllink){

        $web = $_POST['web'];
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];

        $sql="INSERT INTO `tbl_name` (`web`, `urllink`, `cat`) VALUES ('".$web."', '".$urllink."', '".$cat."')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die("<BR>Error Adding!!<BR>".mysql_error()) ;


    }
  header("location:index.php");
 }
```

Let me know if this solve your problem

Comment: Same problem only inserting an one table - every time i tried to insert the URL links i need to change the "web" name also otherwise its shows blank page without error. why?

Comment: I did not get this "only inserting an one table". Please explain first line. what you are trying to say.

Comment: I am using loop to create input box each has different url in it and i want to insert all url with Categories(cat) name and website(web) name in database. above provided script only inserting only one url link in the database.

Comment: I test the my code its working properly. Please check this updated code. If this did not work for you than you can mail me your files.